# Função Jquery.click() com problemas para executar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, aplicação-web

Segundo o meu código abaixo, quando clico no botão `Ver senha` na web está fazendo um `GET` quando na verdade quero apenas que mostre o campo senha. O que pode estar de errado?

```js
$('.passwordShowLabel').hide();
$('#passwordShow').hide();
$('#password').removeAttr("required");
$('#confirmPassword').removeAttr("required");

$('#btnPasswordEditDesistir').hide();
var checkbox = $('#chkPassword');
var checked = checkbox.prop("checked");

$('#btnPasswordEdit').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#btnPasswordEditDesistir').show("slow");
  $('#passwordSection').show("slow");
  $('#password').attr('required', 'true');
  $('#confirmPassword').attr('required', 'true');
});

$('#btnPasswordEditDesistir').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#btnPasswordEdit').show("slow");
  $('#passwordSection').hide("slow");
  $('#password').removeAttr("required");
  $('#confirmPassword').removeAttr("required");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xl-12">

  <div class="pull-left">

    <button id="btnPasswordEdit" class="btn btn-info">
              Editar
             </button>

    <button id="btnPasswordEditDesistir" class="btn btn-secondary">
              Desistir
             </button>


    <button id="btnPasswordView" class="btn btn-info">
              Ver Senha
             </button>

  </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group">


  <label class="passwordShowLabel control-label" for="passwordShow" title="" style="display: none;">Senha atual    </label>

  <div class="">


    <input title="" id="passwordShow" name="object.passwordRoundTripV1" type="text" class="form-control  readonly " placeholder="" value="12345678a" style="display: none;" readonly="readonly">
    <span class="help-block">  </span>





  </div>


</div>


<section id="passwordSection" style="display: none;">

  <div class="col-xl-12">

    <div class="form-group">


      <label class=" control-label" for="password" title="">Senha    </label>

      <div class="">


        <input title="" id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="">
        <span class="help-block">  </span>





      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="form-group">


      <label class=" control-label" for="confirmPassword" title="">Confirmar senha    </label>

      <div class="">


        <input title="" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control  " placeholder="" value="">
        <span class="help-block">  </span>





      </div>


    </div>






  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Este é todo seu código HTML? Se for só um trecho, esse trecho está dentro da tag `<form>`?

Comment: Esta sim @TiagoA, porem tem outros button que funcionam normalmente, o button de enviar e desistir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso seu botão esteja dentro de uma tag `<form>` será necessário cancelar o evento para que botão não envie o formulário. Assim:

De:

```js
$('#btnPasswordEdit').click(function() {
```

Para:

```js
$('#btnPasswordEdit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Resolveu muito obrigado